# How to manipulate z-index using javascript

Tags: javascript, z-index

Suppose I have two divs :

```
<div id="divred"></div>
<div id="divgreen"></div>
```

Then I want to manipulate their z-index to bring the second div to front:

```
document.getElementById("divgreen").zIndex="2";
```

It will fail.

Some people told me that there is an excuse for this behavior, all objects must have positioning specified and there are multiple stacks so -10 in a top stack is still higher than 100 in a lower stack.

That did not help though. I want to know how to ensure that multiple html objects are in same stacking context so that I can play with z-index?

Take this jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/4Lg8a/30/
Can you bring the red div to front without changing the initial positioning?

Here is the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Lg8a/45/embedded/

It works in Webkit, but not in FF28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the solution long ago but forgot to post.

Any 3D transformation invalidates z-index. So I need to use 3D positioning (translateZ) to bring the div to front.

Answer (score 3):

`z-index` is a style not a property of the DOM node, so it's

```
document.getElementById("divred").style.zIndex = "10";
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lg8a/31/)

Comment: That was a silly mistake. I have updated the code with the full design. It works in Webkit, but not in Gecko (FF28). Can you check?